# Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Tags: c#

I'm new in C# and I'm writing API test. I need to write test which will create new user. Here it is:

```
        public async Task CreatingNewUser_Returns200()
        {
            string client = BaseClass.mainURL;
            var json = SettingsHelper.ReadSetting("NewUser");
            httpc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(BaseClass.authKey, BaseClass.authValue);
            var content = new StringContent(json);
            var response = await httpc.PostAsync(client, content);
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
```

Also, I have SettingsHelper class with two methods to make my json readable:

```
private static JObject _jObject;

        public static string ReadSetting(string name)
        {
            var parts = name.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            JToken token = GetObject();
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                token = token[part];
                if (token == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return token.Value<string>();
        }

        private static JObject GetObject()
        {
            if (_jObject != null)
            {
                return _jObject;
            }

            var filename = Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)!,
                "appsettings.json");
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filename);

            _jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

            return _jObject;
        }
```

And I have appsettings.json file with my user:

```
 "NewUser": {
    "externalDealId": "6051",
    "Id": "12312111" // and so on
}
```

But when I launch this test I get an error (title name). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code to

```cs
public static string ReadSetting(string name)
{
    var parts = name.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    JObject jObj= GetObject();
    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        var token = jObj[part];
        if (token == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
           return token.ToString();
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Actually, there is still a logic which needs to be noticed `var parts = name.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` may mean that support multiple setting results. But logic in the ReadSetting function is not. It only return the first setting is matched.

Comment: Thx for an answer! But what should this method return? Now it gives an error that "not all code paths returns the value". I suppose there should be one more "return" before the last brace

Comment: @maitre I have updated it. You could try again.

Comment: After replacing my code with yours I get 2 problems: I get SystemFormatException for my AuthKey and AuthValue in this test and System.Uri.FormatException for all other tests =(

Comment: You could check BaseClass.mainURL, AuthKey, and AuthValue, I think they are not valid values.

Comment: These variables are OK for all other tests, but they are not OK only for this test

Comment: I slightly reworked my test and now it works, but now I need to have 2 'ReadSetting' method (I think I'll handle it in some way). Thank you!